# Adding tables into the schema when they already have data stored in them

Tags: installation, updating

How do I add tables (with stored data) that already exist in the Drupal database to the schema, without destroying the saved data?

I'm taking over some work and finding that there's no use in the `MY_MODULE.install` file of schema definition and therefore no current use of `hook_update_N()` I've looked in the `MY_DRUPAL_DB.system` table and the module has `system.schema_version` of `-1` which according to the table's description means:

> -1 if the module is not installed (its tables do not exist); 0 or the largest N Of the module's hook_update_N() function that has either been run or existed when the module was first installed.

The weird thing is that there is a .install file and it has a `hook_install()` which installs new role permissions. So there is something strange going on as I can't even use `hook_update_N` to add the schema (which I created by downloading the Schema API module and generating the schema defining code in `localhost/admin/structure/schema/`)

Comment: If module is already enabled just go to install file and define hook_schema.. If module is not exit define the module, enable the module and write hook_schema in install file..

Comment: Why is this downvoted?!

Comment: In the `hook_schema` [page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) it says: "This hook is called at install and uninstall time" which I interpret as being inappropriate here, is it not? It then later says "The tables declared by this hook will be automatically created when the module is first enabled" - they are already there, so again it seems inappropriate, am I misunderstanding?

Comment: _How do I add tables (with stored data) that already exist in the Drupal database to the schema, without destroying the saved data?_ as written that's impossible (you would need to get the data out, drop the table, re-add the table, insert the data). What are you actually trying to do, though? Do you mean to ask about adding _fields_ into the schema when the table already exists?

Comment: @Clive I had this problem when I was writing custom module. It was easier to manually play with tables in database in dev stage. But then I needed to make a schema of them. But tables was already in DB, with data in them. Long story short, I did exactly what you described above.

Comment: OK - well your experience suggests I ought to comply! Thanks to you both, unless someone else answers - I will be doing Clive/ Molot's suggestion.